# Run VxWorks on VMware

Tags: vxworks, rtos, vmware-workstation

I'm a newbie to VxWorks but I've worked with other RTOSes. Similar to others, can I run the VxWorks RTOS on VMware as target on my windows development host?
I did not find any VxWorks iso or vmdk file anywhere, how can I get one?

Can someone help me out here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hope this Helps --> https://virtuallyfun.com/wordpress/2015/10/22/you-can-run-vxworks-too/

Comment: Hey @SmAster thanks for replying but this blog is an old one and the link to download the zip files is not working anymore. I need clarity on this, I've an account on windshare.windriver.com. Is it available there or somewhere else? because I'm willing to get the evaluation license but I'm unable to find the link

Comment: In forums people claim that they are using the VxWorks on VMware but you need to research deeper to find it..bcz no .iso is found in 20 first searches in google.

Answer (score 0):

Would the VxWorks Simulator be sufficient enough for you? It comes integrated with Workbench and is pretty easy to setup. Your Wind River installation should come with a PDF titled "Wind River VxWorks Simulator User's Guide". You can to target debugging, test bootloaders. A big drawback to this approach would be that there might be missing device drivers and you might need to change your kernel to work appropriately for the simulator. But if the VxWorks Simulator meets your needs, then I would suggest you take that route.